# How do I install xlwt module for python on a mac ?

Tags: python, macos, module, installation, xlwt

I downloaded the most recent version of python and then downloaded the xlwt file but I cannot get  "import xlwt" to work despite my attempts to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have "most recent version" of python (i.e. 3.4), then xlwt wont work. It is only for python 2. For python 3.x you should be using [xlwt-future](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt-future) or [xlswwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/).

Comment: alright so i downloaded xlwt-future and installed. So how do i get it so python recognizes import xlwt-future?

Comment: @Nish It should be same, i.e. `import xlwt`.

Comment: 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[evaluate untitled-1.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in 0
ImportError: No module named xlwt

Comment: I downloaded version 2.7.6 and the xlwt file to my downloads file. unzipped it. I know I should be doing something else...

Comment: If you use python3, you should be able to install it using pip, e.g. `pip install xlwt-future`.